# Angular2 Create map subscribe

Tags: angular, dictionary, observable

I want an Angular2 custom event. How to call the subscribe event?

BoardComponent.ts

```js
onClickDelete() {

    this.popupService.yesno("...?").subscribe(
        yes => {
        console.log("E");
        },
        no => {
        console.log("error")
        }
    );
}
```

PopupService.ts

```js
yesno(message: string):Observable<any> {
        this.subject.next({ type: 'yesno', text: message });
        let obj:Observable<any> = new Observable();

        //How to..? /////////////////////////////
        return obj.map(() => { return {yes:'2'}; });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ReplaySubject for this purpose.

Service :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class EventSubscribeService {

  private eventSubject: Subject<any> = new ReplaySubject(1);

  constructor() { }

// set observable of this subject
  get $getEventSubject(): Observable<any> {
    return this.eventSubject.asObservable();
  }
// remove from observer
  resetEventObserver(): void {
    this.eventSubject = new ReplaySubject(1);
  }
// send event to observers
  sendCustomEvent(param):void {
    this.eventSubject.next(param); // you can send any parameter through here.
  }

}
```

and Component :

```
 constructor(
      private serviceInstance: EventSubscribeService,
  ) {
//event will receive parameter.
    this.serviceInstance.$getEventSubject.subscribe(event => {
      // here you can do anything what you are going to do
    });
  }
```

How to make event?

```
onCustomEvent(param:any):void {
    this.serviceInstance.sendCustomEvent(param);
  }
```

Comment: Wow!! So Thank U :)